# Count 3 seconds in while loop

Tags: c, microcontroller

I'm currently developing a car racing game in 'C'. I have a process function that is always in loop until game_over is set to true. In the process function, I have a function that tests to see if the car is parked next a fuel stop, once parked, the car stops and fuel is restored.

I would like to know how i can count 3 seconds since the car has stopped for fuel, and then let the game resume after that 3 seconds.

I have tried storing the current time in an variable and added '3 seconds' onto that value, and wait for the time to reach this before continuing. This obviously does not work as loop constantly updates that current time.

```
if (fuel_stop_left() || fuel_stop_right()) {
   fuelRemaining = 10000;
   acceleration = 0;
}
```

Comment: Since it is tagged as _microcontroller_, why don't you use a timer interrupt?

Comment: I have a timer interrupt setup, however, it begins counting at the start of the program. I guess my main question is trying to store a the value, and not have it update every loop. Not sure if possible

Comment: Just add another state, if (busy_fueling()) { /* check if time expired */ }

Comment: Show us what you tried.  I don't understand why you would add 3 seconds to the current time repeatedly in the loop.  Just do it once before the loop.  It's not clear what your hangup is.

Comment: Why would you wait for 3 seconds? Why not add fuel to the car when at a stop in increments till the tank is full. Then the game resumes. That way stopping with half a tank left will resume quicker than stopping on empty.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, the stimulus states that the vehicle must be stopped at the fuel stop for 3 seconds to get a full tank, even if it has used a small amount of fuel. I'm planning to add a function that adds fuel linearly.

Comment: @kkrambo, the if statement above '(if (fuel_stop_left() || fuel_stop_right()) {}'  is in a function named process. Process is looped under the main function, this is so i can be constantly updating the vehicles position on the screen and checking whether the vehicle has stopped at the fuel stop. Because the 'if' statement is in the process loop, I cannot have a function outside the process function that'll call when to start counting as it will not know when to start. And i cannot call that function in the loop as the counter will be updated every loop.

Comment: Your comment doesn't clear anything up.  Edit your question and include all the relevant code.  Do you expect the loop to block for three seconds or do you want the loop to continue to run during the three seconds?  What is your method for getting the current time?  Does the loop run at a regular (periodic) interval such that an iteration can be used as a time increment?

Answer (score 1):

```
clock_t begin;
double time_spent;
unsigned int i;

/* Mark beginning time */
begin = clock();
for (i=0;1;i++)
    {
    printf("hello\n");
    /* Get CPU time since loop started */
    time_spent = (double)(clock() - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    if (time_spent>=3.0)
        break;
    }
```

This code should  help you solve your problem I guess. Don't forget to #include time.h at the beginning of your code.

Comment: I am coding for a micro controller so I cant include time.h. I have a timer interrupt set up, so your logic may work.

Comment: generally you should also avoid `double` in microcontrollers either, except in certain cases. And it's better to use timers instead of wasting CPU usage for such tasks

Answer (score 0):

You can set your timer to 100ms for example. Then you are gonna need to use a variable to count for three seconds and set a flag. In your `main()` check the status of that flag and do whatever you want to do, then clear the flag.

Here is a simple idea:

```
unsigned int cnt = 0;
bool isThreeSecs = false;

// Set this interrupt to 100ms
void myTimerInterrupt()
{
  cnt++;
  if (cnt == 30) // 100ms * 30 = 3 secs
  {
    isThreeSecs = true; // Set your flag here
    cnt = 0; // Clear the cnt variable for next use
  }
}

int main()
{
  // Some stuff
  if (isCarStopped()) // Check if the car has stopped
  {
    // Start your timer here and check your flag
    if (isThreeSecs)
    {
      letMeGo();
      isThreeSecs = false; // Clear the flag
    }
  }
}
```

The implementation may differ depending on your algorithm. You may want to use a `while` loop around the `isThreeSecs` check in the `main()` to prevent doing anything else, for example. I just wanted to give you an idea.